# C# Monotouch/Xamarin - Replace Entire Tab Button With Image In UITabBarController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, xamarin

Is it possible to replace the entire tab button for each tab with a different image in the UITabBarController?

**INSTEAD OF THIS - (Standard Default Tab Controller Appearance)**

[image]

**DO THIS - (Custom Tab Controller Appearance Using Images)**

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Customization of the UITabBarController seems pretty nasty. You can change the tint colour, but that affects the colour of the tab image in it's various selected/not-selected states....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not obvious. But here's how to use full colored images and optionally omit the text label.

```
var tabBarItem = new UITabBarItem("Item Text", null, 1);
tabBarItem.SetFinishedImages(UIImage.FromBundle("./Images/addexpense.png"), UIImage.FromBundle("./Images/addexpense.png"));

var controllerToAdd = new UIViewController()
{
    TabBarItem = tabBarItem
};

tabBarController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[]
{
 controllerToAdd
};
```

The result can then look something like this (of course you can also get rid of the text completely by omitting the "Item Text" shown in my example):

[image: Screenshot from my Coinsitter App]

Comment: Thanks. So presumably your code shows how to change the actual tab image itself on a per-tab basis. How have you changed the entire background image of the tab control to be that single orange/brown textured image?

Comment: @Goober Different question, but anyway. `tabBarController.TabBar.BackgroundImage = Util.LoadBundleImage("./Images/tabbar_background.png");` - if you're happy with my answer, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks. The only follow up that I have is that your answer is deprecated in iOS7. I've looked at the UITabBarItem class on the Apple Docs, and simply setting the SelectedImage property doesn't produce the same result. Are you supporting iOS7 also with this same code?

Comment: @Goober You're supposed to set the `Image` property now in iOS7. If you want to use the same image if selected, set the `SelectedImage` property to the same image.