# UITabbar in ios7 for monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios7

I am changing tabar to work in ios7 I am having one image for selected as well as unselected tabbarItem image.And as SetFinishedImages() has deprecated in ios7.So how should I apply one image for selected as well as unselected tabaritem.Which method should I use in xamarin for this.And how to differentiate that tabbaritem is selected/unselected as I am using one image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Monotouch/Xamarin - Replace Entire Tab Button With Image In UITabBarController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660401/c-sharp-monotouch-xamarin-replace-entire-tab-button-with-image-in-uitabbarcont)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Appearance:

```cs
UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundImage = UIImage...
UITabBar.Appearance.SelectoinIndicatorImage = UIImage...
```